# Error in multi main Module not found: 'babel'

Tags: npm-install, babeljs

I am getting the below error while running [this](https://github.com/mbeaudru/ethereum-todolist/?ref=dappnews) project,

```
Error in multi main
Module not found: 'babel' in C:\Users\Fahad Uddin\Desktop\ethereum-todolist-master
```

I am looking for a solution. I have read many old answers but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yes.When I run that it says a program is already running on localhost:3000

Comment: That's not what `npm install` does.  Run `npm install`